# zsh auto-complete 'tab' auto-capitalization - need fix

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

All - Recently I have seen the 'zsh' on Mac OS Monterey 12.1 is auto-capitalizing commands on pressing the tab (auto-completion) which is irritating + causing issues now & then while I am scripting.

Any fixes?

Tried already:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit 
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
```

GIF to show the behavior: [zsh auto-cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruDPC.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by changing the configuration of a **text-expander app** causing "auto-capitalization" across all apps.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).